# Сортировка выбором. Поясните момент

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм, сортировка

За комментировал строки которые не могу понять, помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

```
for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++) {

                int minVal = x;

                for (int j = x + 1; j < arrOne.Length; j++) if (arrOne[minVal] > arrOne[j]) minVal = j;

                int c = arrOne[minVal]; // ???????
                arrOne[minVal] = arrOne[x]; // меняю местами минимальный и очередной элемент массива
                arrOne[x] = c; // ???????


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбрали минимальный элемент и свопнули его с текущим через промежуточную переменную.

Операция `=` - это присваивание, а не обмен. Вот есть у тебя две коробки - в одной красный шарик, а в другой - синий. Но коробки не простые - ты можешь класть в другие места копии того, что в ни есть, но если ты кладёшь что-то в коробку, то то, что там лежало раньше исчезает. Ты хочешь и поменять местами. Если ты в коробку с красным положишь синий, то у тебя будет 2 коробки с синими, а красных нет. А если ты сначала положишь красный в третью коробку, то всё получится.

Comment: почему тогда не `arrOne[x] = arrOne[minVal]` ? Зачем использовать промежуточную? Получается, что сначала я ставлю минимальное значение на место очередного, а следующей строкой ставлю очередное на место минимального?

Comment: Во-первых, наоборот, а во-вторых, ну попробуй поменять по-другому...

Comment: По другому не компилируется и я не могу понять почему, поэтому и спрашиваю :l

Comment: o_O Что именно не компилируется? Компилироваться оно будет, а вот работать правильно - нет: `arrOne[minVal] = arrOne[x]; arrOne[x] = arrOne[minVal];`.

Comment: Ну да, я это имел ввиду)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.